# Checkout Error when checking out project from SVN

Tags: sqlite, svn, rad

I am trying to checkout project from SVN and I get this error. It seems to checkout very fast and whenever it reaches 99% it gives me cannot check out error. 
I had my workspace in different Directory and try to switch workspace to a new directory.

```
Error: SQLite error<br>
svn: sqlite: disk I/O error<br>
svn: sqlite: disk I/O error<br>
svn: no such savepoint: s2832, executing statement 'RELEASE   s2832'<br>
svn: no such savepoint: s2832, executing statement 'ROLLBACK TO s2832'<br>
```

Comment: Do you have a virus scanner doing real time scans? (See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tortoisesvn/ml-HcEEkGO0)

Comment: Are you running in a virtual machine, or on a network file system?

Comment: I am working on network file system. my company has some kind of virus protection system that I don't have control over. Is there are other thing I can do?